# How to search for multiline-parallel text in Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Consider a table with the following headers in a text file

```
    Table name goes here
                                                                     Page 1
    This is column one                 This is   This
                         This is       column    is column
                         column two f   thre f    three f
                                                 and hal f

     Row1 in column 1    Row2InCol2     Row3       Row4InCol4


                                                                     Page 2


 This is column one                   This is     This
                        This is       column    is column
                        column two f   thre f    three f
                                                and hal f


 Grand Total: -       12               13        25
```

I want to search for the column "This is column three f and a hal f" in such a way that when I find this text, I am able to get the String index postion where this column started (Index of "This") and the index postion where this column ended (Index at which the word "hal f" ended, that is Index of 'f'). Note that all the columns contain the word "This" and the letter 'f' and that I should be able to search the start index and end index for any of the columns in similar fashion as explained above.

I want be able to do this because I want to implement a parser that can parse tables in a text file in which the index postion of the column headers and column data is not consistent from one page to another (where form feed character indicates end of page)

I am not looking for any algorithm as such. I want to know whether Pattern and Matcher classes (or any other APIs) support multi-line text searches as explained above?

Comment: Are you sure the table looks like this?

Comment: I think the problem needs to be defined a little better. Does a column contain multiple blocks of data or just a single block per page with a known start/end delimiter?

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes. I have presented the column headers only and not the data in the table as I am more concerned with identifying the width of each column. Once I have the width of a column, I can easily pick up the data for any column I want given that I will have the start index and the end index of each column header, i.e the width of the column.

Comment: @taktek A column can contain multiple blocks of data. Right now I am more concerned with geting the width of each column since I already have an algorithm which works well once I have the width. Note that each table contains a total, Once I find the table name, I parse everything in the way as a row until i reach the total.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pattern which has worked for me in the past.

```
// split on two ore more spaces.
String[] fields = line.split("\\s{2,}");
```

This treats one space as being part of a field.

Comment: I have tried this approach before. This approach fails when one of the columns has a name that spans 2 lines and starts from the second line instead of the first line (See column "This is column two f"),

Comment: You would have to merge the lines together.  The other problem you have is when a field doesn't appear on every line.

Answer (score 0):

Because the text you're searching for is a fixed literal, regex is not the weapon of choice - just use [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) on the whole text, including newlines, from the first `"This"` to the last `"f"`:

```
String target = "This\nThis is       column    is column\n                        column two f   thre f    three f\n                                                and hal f";

int start = input.indexOf(target);
int end = start + target.length();
```

To find the next occurrence, use [`String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) using the previous `end` as `fromIndex`

Comment: I want a generic approach such that if I give an input string say "This is column two f" without any \n, it should start searching this string across multiple lines and get me the start and end index (width) of the column that exactly matched this string. If I use your approach, I am putting a restriction on the code such that I always need to know the position of the new line character, the space character, etc for all the column names for all the possible tables that can appear in the text file. This requires that I implement new code for parsing every new table that is added to the file.

Comment: Using pattern and matcher allows me to use the find() method in a while loop and I am also free to use the start() and end() method to directly get the index positions. Also, Pattern.quote ignores the meta-characters in the column-name if that poses to be a problem in the future.